# show all twig variables in symfony web developer toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, twig

is there an easy way to *always* show the twig vars `{{dump()}}` in the symfony web developer toolbar? I already have implemented a custom data collector but if I add the following lines in my collector templates:

```
<div class="sf-toolbar-info-piece">
    <b>Twig vars</b> {{ dump() }}
</div>
```

only the vars given to the toolbar will be shown not the ones I added in to the render function in the controller.
Basically I want something like the output that you see if you add

```
{% dump %}
```

in your twig template.

Comment: `{{ dump(_context) }}`

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. this displays the same dump output as `dump(_context)`